# cant open atom using atom in CLI

Tags: command-line, software-installation, atom

I had **Atom Editor** in my machine and was using it using the `atom` command. But yesterday I installed **Learn IDE** which is a fork of atom with many changes and now whenever I use `atom` command it opens Learn IDE not the Atom Editor. I uninstalled Learn IDE using

`sudo apt-get --purge remove atom`

and found it is now removed from my system but using the `atom` command does nothing it says

`bash: /usr/bin/atom: No such file or directory`

**Atom** is still there on my system but I can't use the command `atom`. Please Help.

Comment: I know nothing about `atom` (and my look was unhelpful https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=atom as it came up with a game etc); but if it was a fork that you removed thru purge, their fork may have used some of the same files that they didn't change the name of; thus the purge killed atom's files too!.  Thus I'd be tempted to `sudo apt install --reinstall` atom via whatever means you installed it (unless it's a snap - it should be safe, in which case I'd use `whereis atom` & look for it, but I suspect this isn't the case)

Comment: I had downloaded it from ubuntu software @guiverc

Comment: A quick look found it's available via PPA; so a `sudo apt install --reinstall atom` should fix your problem if my theory was correct (the command I used & link provided only looks in default repos for packages; not PPA's)

Comment: it says unable to locate package atom.

Comment: okay - there is also a snapped version I can see in 'ubuntu software'; `sudo snap install atom`  (there is no --reinstall option with snaps) COULD be your fix; but if so I've missed something..

Comment: how about using .deb file  from atom website to install again.

Comment: yep.  i'd suggest `sudo apt install --reinstall ./name-of-atom-file.deb`  which will do the apt install of the local .deb file (`apt` will get any dependencies if required & available, whereas `dpkg` won't)

Comment: yeah it worked.